# Change all null to '' in array of Objects (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, underscore.js

I have this array of objects shown below

```
Object {Results:Array[3]}
    Results:Array[3]
        [0-2]
             0:Object
                    id=null     
                    name: "Rick"
                    Value: "34343"
             1:Object
                    id=2     
                    name: null
                    Value: "2332"
             2:Object
                    id=2     
                    name:'mike'
                    Value: null
```

As you can see, in 1 object i have id as null, 2nd object has name as null and 3rd object has Value as null. Each object has some property as null.

I want to loop through all of these and replace null with ''. Can someone let me know how to achieve this...

Comment: Do you know property names upfront?

Comment: yeah. these 3 properties. id, name and Value.

Comment: Then, what is the problem?  `forEach` and 3 `if` inside.

Comment: You can do it by looping through all of the elements and replacing null with `''`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only needed to Google looping through objects. Here's an example:

#### Looping through every key (if your keys are unknown or you want to do the same for all keys)

```
for (const obj of arr) {
  if (typeof obj !=== 'object') continue;
  for (k in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue;
    v = obj[k];
    if (v === null || v === undefined) {
      obj[k] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

#### If your keys are known:

```
for (const obj of arr) {
  if (obj.name === undefined || obj.name === null) {
    obj.name = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's something quick:

```
var results = [{
    id: null,
    name: "Rick",
    Value: "34343"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: null,
    Value: "2332"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'mike',
    Value: null
}];

results.forEach(function(object){
    for(key in object) {
        if(object[key] == null)
            object[key] = '';
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the elements of the array and over the keys and assign the wanted strings if necessary.

```js
var data = { Results: [{ id: null, name: "Rick", Value: "34343" }, { id: 2, name: null, Value: "2332" }, { id: 2, name: 'mike', Value: null }] };

data.Results.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (o[k] === null) {
            o[k] = '';
        }
    });
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look over your array and all keys and if the property contains `null` replace it with empty string, e.g.:

```
var arr = [
  { id=null name: "Rick" Value: "34343" },
  { id=2 name: null Value: "2332" },
  { id=2 name:'mike' Value: null }
];

arr.forEach(function(o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key) {
      id (o[key] === null) {
        o[key] = '';
      }
    });
});
```